# Cannot import image in public folder to src folder in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

The project structure of Reactjs looks like below:

```
->public
  ->background.jpg
->src
  ->App.js
  ->App.css
```

I am trying to load `background.jpg` in `App.css` like this:
`background-image: url("../public/background.jpg");`

But the image is not getting imported. Instead it says the imports outside of src are not allowed.

How can I resolve this problem?

create-react-app version: 3.4.0

Comment: In one of my previous project, this thing was working fine, but not now!

Answer (score 0):

Create an asset folder inside the src folder and import it again

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But is there any way that I put all the images files in public folder and import them from there?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly import from public folder, but if you wants to do, you can pass the full url then it'll work.

Working code is here:

```css
.body {
    background-image: url("http://localhost:3000/background.jpg");
}
```

Comment: I made a project in react one year ago. In that project, I was able to access images in public folder from anywhere in the project.